# How to merge dataframes based on an "OR" condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Let's say I have two dataframes, and the column names for both are:

```
table 1 columns:
[ShipNumber, TrackNumber, ShipDate, Quantity, Weight]
table 2 columns:
[ShipNumber, TrackNumber, AmountReceived]
```

I want to merge the two tables based on both ShipNumber and TrackNumber. 
However, if i simply use merge in the following way (pseudo code, not real code):

```
tab1.merge(tab2, "left", on=['ShipNumber','TrackNumber'])
```

then, that means the values in both ShipNumber and TrackNumber columns from both tables MUST MATCH.

**However**, in my case, sometimes the ShipNumber column values will match, sometimes the TrackNumber column values will match; **as long as one of the two values match for a row**, I want the merge to happen.

In other words, if row 1 ShipNumber in tab 1 matches row 3 ShipNumber in tab 2, but the TrackNumber in two tables for the two records do not match, I still want to match the two rows from the two tables.

So basically this is a either/or match condition (pesudo code):

```
if tab1.ShipNumber == tab2.ShipNumber OR tab1.TrackNumber == tab2.TrackNumber:
    then merge
```

I hope my question makes sense... 
Any help is really really appreciated!

As suggested, I looked into this post:
[Python pandas merge with OR logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925603/python-pandas-merge-with-or-logic?rq=1)
But it is not completely the same issue I think, as the OP from that post has a mapping file, and so they can simply do 2 merges to solve this. But I dont have a mapping file, rather, I have two df's with same key columns (ShipNumber, TrackNumber)

Comment: did you see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925603/python-pandas-merge-with-or-logic?rq=1

Comment: actually that post does not solve the problem here..

Comment: Hi @Vico I edited my post to include your suggested post, but I think that post did not answer my question :(

Comment: Do you want four columns total in your output?  I.e. `A_tab1`, `A_tab2`, `B_tab1`, `B_tab2`?  It seems like you'll need all of these if only `A` or `B` needs to match on any given row.

Comment: @andrew_reece that is fine if all columns has to be preserved; the key is to merge the tables correctly

Comment: Have you tried running with a join?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ isnt merge and join the same thing?

Comment: Not so. They're slightly different. Have a go and see if it works.

Comment: Anyway, more cannot be said without your data or expected output.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `merge()` and `concat()`.  Then drop any duplicate cases where both `A` and `B` match (thanks @Scott Boston for that final step).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,2,1,4], 'B':[7,8,9,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,5,6,4], 'B':[4,1,8,5]})

df1         df2
   A  B        A  B
0  3  7     0  1  4
1  2  8     1  5  1
2  1  9     2  6  8
3  4  5     3  4  5
```

With these data frames we should see:

- `df1.loc[2]` matches `A` on `df2.loc[0]`
- `df1.loc[1]` matches `B` on `df2.loc[2]`
- `df1.loc[3]` matches both `A` and `B` on `df2.loc[3]`

We'll use suffixes to keep track of what matched where:

```
suff_A = ['_on_A_match_1', '_on_A_match_2']
suff_B = ['_on_B_match_1', '_on_B_match_2']

df = pd.concat([df1.merge(df2, on='A', suffixes=suff_A), 
                df1.merge(df2, on='B', suffixes=suff_B)])

     A  A_on_B_match_1  A_on_B_match_2    B  B_on_A_match_1  B_on_A_match_2
0  1.0             NaN             NaN  NaN             9.0             4.0
1  4.0             NaN             NaN  NaN             5.0             5.0
0  NaN             2.0             6.0  8.0             NaN             NaN
1  NaN             4.0             4.0  5.0             NaN             NaN
```

Note that the second and fourth rows are duplicate matches (for both data frames, `A = 4` and `B = 5`).  We need to remove one of those sets.

```
duplicates = (df.B_on_A_match_1 == df.B_on_A_match_2) # also could remove A_on_B_match
df.loc[~duplicates]

     A  A_on_B_match_1  A_on_B_match_2    B  B_on_A_match_1  B_on_A_match_2
0  1.0             NaN             NaN  NaN             9.0             4.0
0  NaN             2.0             6.0  8.0             NaN             NaN
1  NaN             4.0             4.0  5.0             NaN             NaN
```

Comment: I think you need drop_duplicates after concat to make sure your eliminate record that may have successful joins on both A and B.

Comment: Good catch!  I'll update with the edge case in my sample data.

Comment: is the concat same thing as append in this case?

Comment: Yes, you could also do `df1.merge(on='A').append(df1.merge(on='B'))`.  I think `concat` is often faster.

Comment: @andrew_reece can you explain why you only has one argument "on" for the merge in your code df1.merge(on='A').append(df1.merge(on='B'))? what does that mean?

Comment: It's the equivalent of the `if ... then merge` pseudocode in your original post.  If you're new to the idea, Pandas docs on [Merge, Join, and Concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) are comprehensive and readable.

Comment: How would you set up dups when you have more than 2 columns? IE A, B, C

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest this alternate way for doing merge like this. This seems easier for me.

```
table1["id_to_be_merged"] = table1.apply(
    lambda row: row["ShipNumber"] if pd.notnull(row["ShipNumber"]) else row["TrackNumber"], axis=1)
```

You can add the same column in `table2` as well if needed and then use in `left_in` or `right_on` based on your requirement.

Comment: __apply__ and __lambdas__ are not for beginners, and thus, lacking an explanation, makes the answer not as helpful as could be. You could also make your code a bit more readable. Does it beat the method above in performance?

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem. I think most of the rows for the question asker include both a valid ship number and a valid track number. Also, the question asker isn't looking to match table 1 ship numbers to table 2 track numbers or vice versa. It has to be `(table_1.ShipNumber == table2.ShipNumber) or (table_1.TrackNumber == table2.TrackNumber)` . Matching `table_1.ShipNumber == table_2.TrackNumber` would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['1','2','3'],['4','5']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['1','2','3'],['4','5']])

df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=df1[2].fillna(df1[1]), right_on=df2[2].fillna(df2[1]))

# result
  key_0 0_x 1_x   2_x 0_y 1_y   2_y
0     3   1   2     3   1   2     3
1     5   4   5  None   4   5  None
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34448694)

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.