# Joining two dfs based on different col names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, inner-join

I have two dataframes such as:

```
dfa:
Name  |   ID   |   Amount
Bob      V434      50.00
Jill     B333      22.11
Hank     B442      11.11

dfb:
Name | ID_First | ID_Second | ID_Third
Bob      V434      E333        B442
Karen    V434      E333        B442
Jill     V434      E333        B442
Hank     V434      E333        B442
```

I want to join `dfa` to `dfb`, but the `ID` in `dfa` only corresponds to one of the IDS in `dfb`.

Is there a way I can join `dfa` to `dfb` for `ID` in `dfa` so basically if it matches any of the ids in `dfb` then I can match amount from `dfa`?

Required output would just be:

```
Name | ID_First | ID_Second | ID_Third | Amount 
    Bob      V434      E333        B442     50.00
    Jill    V434      E333        B442      22.11
    Hank     V434      E333        B442     11.11
```

Basically join on Name that exists in both tables, but the `ID` that exists in `dfa` exists in `dfb` under only one of the `ID_First`, second or third columns so the amount that matches for the same name and same ID value but that ID value is only in one of the `IDS` for `dfb`.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re trying to do?

Comment: add the required output

Comment: Where that `55.00` amount came from and why `Jill` is not listed on the desired output as well?

Comment: Do we assume that the name is unique ? The IDs don't seem to be unique thus merging on them will be problematic. Also do you just want to drop the ID column from dfa in the final output?

Comment: yes the name is unique, the output is just an example and not with real exact data

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt a merge on all three, though not sure how efficient that would be. This wouldn't account work for when you have multiple matches across IDs, if such a thing is possible. The following might work;

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for col in ['ID_First', 'ID_Second', 'ID_Third']:
  df = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, left_on='ID', right_on=col, how='left')
  new_df = df if new_df.empty else new_df.append(df)
```

I don't think you can have an 'OR' condition in `pd.merge`.

This is another possibility;

[Python Pandas: How to merge based on an "OR" condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869886/python-pandas-how-to-merge-based-on-an-or-condition)

Answer (score 0):

You can do 3 inner joins with each of your id columns and concatenate them

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Bob','V434',50.00],['Jill','E333',22.11],['Hank','B442',11.11]],
                   columns=['Name','ID','Amount'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['Bob','V434','E333','B442'],
                    ['Karen','V434','E333','B442'],
                    ['Jill','V434','E333','B442'],
                    ['Hank','V434','E333','B442']],
                   columns=['Name','ID_First','ID_Second','ID_Third'])

print(pd.concat([df1.merge(df2, left_on=['ID','Name'], right_on=['ID_First','Name']),
                 df1.merge(df2, left_on=['ID', 'Name'], right_on=['ID_Second', 'Name']),
                 df1.merge(df2, left_on=['ID', 'Name'], right_on=['ID_Third', 'Name'])])[['Name','ID','Amount']])
```

Output:

```
   Name    ID  Amount
0   Bob  V434   50.00
0  Jill  E333   22.11
0  Hank  B442   11.11
```

Improvising on @Ian's answer to get the desired output:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for col in ['ID_First', 'ID_Second', 'ID_Third']:
  df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['ID','Name'], right_on=[col,'Name'], how='inner')
  new_df = df if new_df.empty else new_df.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can do this with a simple `merge` statement as follows.

```py
pd.merge(dfa[['Name', 'Amount']], dfb, how='inner', on='Name')
```

> **Note**: While merging `dfa` and `dfb`, the columns, `dfa.ID` and `dfb.ID` *do not act like primary keys*, neither are their values unique. The only thing that matters here is to **inner join** `dfa` and `dfb` using the *"Name"* column.

**Output**:
[image]

### For Reproducibility

You may load the data and test the solution given above, using the following code-block

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Example Data
dfa = """
Name  |   ID   |   Amount
Bob   |  V434  |   50.00
Jill  |  B333  |   22.11
Hank  |  B442  |   11.11
"""
dfb = """
Name  | ID_First | ID_Second | ID_Third
Bob   |  V434    | E333      | B442
Karen |  V434    | E333      | B442
Jill  |  V434    | E333      | B442
Hank  |  V434    | E333      | B442
"""

# Load Data and Clean up empty spaces 
# in headers and columns
dfa = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dfa), sep='|')
dfb = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dfb), sep='|')
dfa.columns = dfa.columns.str.strip()
dfb.columns = dfb.columns.str.strip()
for col in dfa.columns:
    if col=='Amount':
        dfa[col] = dfa[col].astype(str).str.strip().astype(float)
    else:    
        dfa[col] = dfa[col].str.strip()
for col in dfb.columns:
    dfb[col] = dfb[col].str.strip()

# merge dfa and dfb: Note that dfa.ID and dfb.ID do not act 
# like primary keys, neither are their values unique. 
# The only thing that matters here is to inner join dfa 
# and dfb using the "Name" column.  

pd.merge(dfa[['Name', 'Amount']], dfb, how='inner', on='Name')
```