# Look up data from other table with apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

```py
table = pd.DataFrame(
          columns=["Name", "Size", "Color"], 
          data=[['A', 1, 'Red'], ['B', 2, 'Green'], ['C', 3, 'Blue']]
        )
```

[image]

And a lookup table that looks like this:

```py
lookup = pd.DataFrame(
           columns=["Color", "Source", "Lead Days"], 
           data=[["Red", "Europe", 2], 
                 ["Green", "Europe", 3], 
                 ["Blue", "US", 1], 
                 ["Yellow", "Europe", 2]]
         )
```

[image]

How might I add columns "Source" and "Lead Days" to `table` by looking up "Color" from `lookup`?

A story sometimes helps.

`table` has all the items I need to order.

`lookup` has where I order them from and how long it takes.

I want to transform `table` so that it can show the "Source" and "Lead Days" for each item I need to order.

Here's what the final table should look like:

[image]

Note: while I'm sure there's a way to do this with merge, or top level table operations. In the spirit of [Minimally Sufficient Pandas](https://medium.com/dunder-data/minimally-sufficient-pandas-a8e67f2a2428), and to avoid the huge kluge that is pandas' over-provisioning of operations, I'd prefer to do it with `apply`. Apply is nice because it's easy to consistently reach for `apply` in all situations.

Here's my current approach, but it results in the error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

To me, this makes little sense, since I'm returning a list of length 2 and putting it into two columns. But I'm sure pandas has its reasons for being anti-intuitive here.

```py
lookup_columns = ["Source", "Lead Days"]
table[lookup_columns] = table.apply(
    lambda row: 
          lookup.query('`Color` == "{color}"'.format(color=row["Color"])).loc[:, lookup_columns].values[0]
      , axis = 1)
```

Comment: According to the article you referenced the merge operation is an 'acceptable' operation see 'Best of the API' section. As others have pointed out apply is unnecessarily computationally expensive and complicated / hard for others to understand.

Comment: @quizzical_panini thanks for pointing that out. The article isn't my sacred text, it's just pointing in the same direction as this question; i.e. simplification. Is there a way to merge based on multiple criteria: e.g. `x > 3 and Color = "Red" (that's another criteria of my current lookup)? Also, what happens if multiple columns match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `result_type="expand"`:

```
lookup_columns = ["Source", "Lead Days"]
table[lookup_columns] = table.apply(
    lambda row:
    lookup.query('`Color` == "{color}"'.format(color=row["Color"])).loc[:, lookup_columns].values[0]
    , axis=1, result_type="expand")

print(table)

  Name  Size  Color  Source  Lead Days
0    A     1    Red  Europe          2
1    B     2  Green  Europe          3
2    C     3   Blue      US          1
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?#pandas.DataFrame.apply) (emphasis mine):

> result_type {‘expand’, ‘reduce’, ‘broadcast’, None}, default None
> These only act when axis=1 (columns):
> **‘expand’** : list-like results will be turned into columns.

Comment: damn can't believe that was the issue. Ok, not to be too picky, is there any way I can modify the return value so that I don't have to use the `result_type` parameter? I know I sound like I don't want to learn the tool... well yeah I guess I don't want to learn it. I can barely stand writing `axis=1` each time haha

Comment: I know I sound ridiculous. I guess pandas violates my sensibilities. I've been using it for 3 years on and off and I'm so annoyed that whenever I return to it it's such a damn heavy relearning process to get it to do the extremely simple things I want it to do

Comment: @Connor I'm not sure if there is way to achieve what you want without setting the result_type argument.

Answer (score 2):

With `apply`, you can do:

```
>>> pd.concat([table, table['Color'].apply(lambda x: lookup.loc[lookup['Color'] == x, ['Source', 'Lead Days']].squeeze())], axis=1)

  Name  Size  Color  Source  Lead Days
0    A     1    Red  Europe          2
1    B     2  Green  Europe          3
2    C     3   Blue      US          1
```

---

**Old answer**

Use `pd.merge`:

```
>>> pd.merge(table, lookup, how='left', on='Color')

  Name  Size  Color  Source  Lead Days
0    A     1    Red  Europe          2
1    B     2  Green  Europe          3
2    C     3   Blue      US          1
```

Comment: see note on using merge?

Comment: You're right. Sorry :)

Comment: Do you know `apply` is a slow function (like a loop)

Comment: It's not as slow as a for loop. Plus, I'm interested in doing speedy (not meaning performant) data analysis. poitroae

Comment: I.e. fast feedback without looking at api docs is most important

Comment: There's another reason not to use `merge` (I'm feeling defensive :) in my actual usecase I need to select based on multiple criteria, for which I think `query` is likely best suited? Is there a way to merge based on criteria like `x > 3 and `Color` = "Red"`?

Comment: @wwnde did you see this :point-up:?

Comment: What do you mean by `x > 3`. `x` is a color not the whole row. It's possible to pass row to `apply`. Give a concrete example, I will update my answer.

Comment: obviously, yes the apply route will work for selecting based on multiple criteria. I’m wondering if merge has any solutions for selecting rows based on multiple criteria

Comment: You have to create on-the-fly columns based on criteria before merging.

Comment:  huh could you give an example of what that might look like?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869886/python-pandas-how-to-merge-based-on-an-or-condition/45870198

Answer (score 2):

I wouldnt' use apply. It is computationally expensive. For your case, join will suffice.

```
table.set_index('Color').join(lookup.set_index('Color')).reset_index()



    Color Name  Size  Source  Lead Days
0    Red    A     1  Europe          2
1  Green    B     2  Europe          3
2   Blue    C     3      US          1
```